# missing type id property '@class' with latest versions of spring data redis, jedis, jackson

Tags: serialization, jackson, jackson-databind, spring-data-redis, jedis

I am seeing the below stacktrace with latest versions of spring-data-redis, jedis, jackson

````
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32     at [Source: (byte[])"["java.util.LinkedHashSet",[{"@class":IntegrationConfig","entities":["java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList",[{"name":"launch""nested_a"[truncated 339059 bytes]; line: 1, column: 307] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashSet[0]->IntegrationConfig["onboarding_config"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.aw.dpa.common.pipeline.config.OnboardingConfig]: missing type id property '@class' (for POJO property 'onboarding_config')
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32     at [Source: (byte[])"["java.util.LinkedHashSet",[{"@class":"IntegrationConfig","entities":["java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList",[{"name":"launch","nested_a"[truncated 339059 bytes]; line: 1, column: 307] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashSet[0]->IntegrationConfig["onboarding_config"])
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:164)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:142)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:380)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.get(DefaultHashOperations.java:57)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.get(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:65)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.DefaultRedisMap.get(DefaultRedisMap.java:160)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.DefaultRedisMap.putIfAbsent(DefaultRedisMap.java:281)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at com.aw.dpa.distributable.redis.map.RedisMapImpl.putIfAbsent(RedisMapImpl.java:80)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at PipelineConfigUpdateManager.doPostConstruct(PipelineConfigUpdateManager.java:100)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor429.invoke(Unknown Source)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32        ... 60 common frames omitted
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class OnboardingConfig]: missing type id property '@class' (for POJO property 'onboarding_config')
build   28-Jul-2022 18:45:32     at [Source: (byte[])"["java.util.LinkedHashSet",[{"@class":"IntegrationConfig","entities":["java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList",[{"name":"launch","nested_a"[truncated 339059 bytes]; line: 1, column: 307] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashSet[0]->IntegrationConfig["onboarding_config"])```

There have been no changes to POJOs , the only changes are the version bumps for spring-data-redis, jedis, jackson-databind.
````

Comment: which versions are you referring to? do you have some code to look at? A reproducer ideally.